# Pass function pointer across files in CUDA

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda, function-pointers

I've created a function that gives me a pointer to a function that I can use without any problem in CUDA kernels of the same file (using `(*myfunc_given_in_argument)(x)` in the kernel).

But my problem is that I'm unable to use the function I get in another file using the same method (there is not any visual difference), the execution  of the kernel gives me a `misaligned address error` that I understand generally but not here.

For a more detailed approach, here is a minimal example:
`file1.cu`, everything works great here

```cpp
typedef float (*funcPtr)(float);

__device__ float device_relu(float x) {
    return fmaxf(0, x);
}

__device__ funcPtr ptr_relu = device_relu;

funcPtr get_activation_function_cuda(int activation) {
    funcPtr host_function;
    
    switch (activation) {
        case RELU:
            gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&host_function, ptr_relu, sizeof(funcPtr)));
            break;
        ...
    }
    return host_function;
}

__global__ void kernel1(funcPtr f,...) {
    ...
    x[...] = (*f)(x[...]); // No problem here
    ...
}

void func1(int activation) {
    ...
    funcPtr activation_function = get_activation_function_cuda(activation);

    apply_function_input_kernel<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(activation_function, ...);
    ...
}
```

`file2.cu`, I get `misaligned address error` on the next `GpuErrchk` (which I didn't include for readability)

```cpp
#include ".../file1.h"

__global__ void kernel2(..., funcPtr d_f) {
    ...

    float tmp=0;
    for (int j=0; j < size_output; j++) {
        tmp += output[j]*weights[idx][j];
    }
    input[idx] = tmp*( (*d_f)(input_z[idx]) );
}

void backward_dense_device(...) {
    dim3 gridSize1(i_div_up(size_input, BLOCKSIZE_x));
    dim3 blockSize1(BLOCKSIZE_x);

    funcPtr d_function = get_activation_function_cuda(RELU);

    kernel2<<<gridSize1, blockSize1>>>(..., d_function); 
}
```

PS: I compile the following way:

```bash
nvcc  -g  -c src/file1.cu -o build/file1.o
nvcc  -g  -c src/file2.cu -o build/file2.o
...  # A bunch of other files, .c and .cu
gcc  -c src/main.c -o build/main.cuda.o  -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu99 -g -O3 -DUSE_CUDA -lcuda -I/opt/cuda/include
nvcc  -ljpeg -Xcompiler -fopenmp -g  build/main.cuda.o build/file1.o build/file2.o -o build/main
# Note: My main file is a .c file so I compile it to .o and then use nvcc to link without falling back to gcc
```

I can't understand what is different in the second file.
I've tried doing the manual steps to get a function pointer in `file2.cu`, it worked fine.
I've also tried to move the whole non-working part of my code from `file2.cu` to `file1.cu` and I then got no problem, but I don't evaluate this as a viable option.
What am I missing ? A function keyword ? A compiler option ? Thank for your help

Comment: If you are going to call device functions compiled in different translation units, you need to use separate compilation of those device functions. This is discussed in great detail in the programming guide and places like [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/)